# what to do while error comes in running the flutter project

Tags: download

error like below mentioned,

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not download kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.7.10.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.7.10)
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-compiler-embeddable/1.7.10/kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.7.10.jar'.
> > Read timed out

i have to know how solve this problem

Comment: Hi @Dinesh Dinesh the error above is indicating that the download of a dependency from Maven central (repo.maven.apache.org) failed and so the Android build of your project is failing. This could have been an Internet connectivity issue as the specific error says "read timed out" which usually happens when the remote server is unreachable. Maven central most assuredly has something like 99.999% uptime (I use it every day) 

I would try again from a different network or try again later.  I think your Internet connection was just down for a moment during the build or your IDE is misconfigured.